# Is there a way to speed up a mysqli query which produces lots of data?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query in my PHP code which returns about 25,000 rows with 6 columns of data taken from 4 different tables. This is creating a major bottleneck, though.  In the following code, store_result() takes about 20 seconds to execute:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($var0, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'field0' => $var0,
        'field1' => $var1,
        'field2' => $var2,
        'field3' => $var3,
        'field4' => $var4,
        'field5' => $var5,
    );
}
```

I've also tried the same query without preparing it:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query($query);
$rows = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

but I didn't see any improvement; instead of store_result() taking 20 seconds, query() took 20 seconds instead.

Because the slow-down comes from store_result() instead of execute(), would optimizing the query itself help here at all?  If not, does anyone have any other suggestions?  Or am I just trying to transfer a lot of data and there's no help for it?

Note that I don't have access to mysqlnd, I only have to run the query once and it doesn't have any user input which needs to be escaped, if that's relevant for any suggested solutions.

Comment: How long does it take for the same query to dump its results on the mysql command line, or perhaps straight to a CSV file or such? In other words: how long does the server take on its own, taking PHP out of the equation?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be the lack of proper indexes. Have you tried to [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) your query?

You'd need to provide more context to get a better answer :

- What is the query?
- What is the structure of the 4 tables?
- What is the approximate size of one selected row (a few bytes versus
  megabytes of blob/text)?
- Is the mysql database on the same server as your php script?
- If the db server and the php server are on two different machines,
  what is the bandwidth between them?

Answer (score 0):

Query optimization is the key. First step is to assure that your queries are stable in the sense that you are utilizing your keys efficiently. Proper usage of indexes can also speed up your querying.